# Utilizar un OR dentro de un IF MAcros

Tags: vba

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
For i = 1 To j
        If Sheets("Detalle sin TDC vista").Range("H" & i) = "Tarjeta" or Sheets("Detalle sin TDC vista").Range("H" & i) = "test" Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
Next
```

lo que estoy haciendo es leer una columna de Excel ya que tengo que eliminar los registros que se llamen Tarjeta y Vista, al utilizar el OR no funciona pero si quito el Or y solo dejo una de las dos sentencias si funciona, me podrian decir si esta es la manera correcta de utilizar un or dentro de un if

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que no te funciona? ¿Te da algún tipo de error o algo?

Answer (score 0):

Has probado con:

```
For i = 1 To j
        If Sheets("Detalle sin TDC vista").Range("H" & i) = "Tarjeta"  Then
              Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf Sheets("Detalle sin TDC vista").Range("H" & i) = "test" Then
              Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
Next
```